# Print issue from Internet Explorer - side-by-side columns

Tags: css, printing, css-float

i have a setup of 2 floated columns - using a grid setup, based on bootstrap 2.0.3.

each column is 5/12 of the width.

in Firefox - the page prints correctly: the 2 columns are side by side.
in Explorer (9 and 10) - the columns are displayed fine, but for printing - they are just one after the other, not side by side.

i have tried setting the column to `display:inline`, and also tried adding `float: left` but nothing seems to help:

FIDDLE LINK: http://cssdesk.com/7vamd

any ideas appreciated!
thanks

Comment: Try using `media="print"`

Comment: use it on what? i already have a print media css file. bottom line (with it or without it) the page print layout works on FF, but not IE.  why...?